# Wordpress custom post type: parent child relationship

Tags: wordpress

How can I maintain parent child relationship in custom post type without using any plugins in wordpress ?

For eg:
when you visit this site

> http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/

you can find volunteer impact menu. Under this menu I've made `volunteers_impact` taxonomy to categorized the volunteer impact by using Plugins called gdcpt custom post type. But I want to do this without using any plugins, and most important thing is that I want to maintain parent child relationship.

In this site, when you click

> www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteers_impact/volunteering-impact-2013

you will find volunteer impact of 2013 only. The taxonomy name is `voluteers_impact`, but I want to keep taxonomy name `volunteer-impact` which is good for SEO purposes.

While giving custom post type and taxonomy name, this plugins suggest to use only underscore to join two words.

When you click single page suppose

> http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/women-empowerment-2013/

you will see the difference of post name (volunteer-impact) and taxonomy name (volunteers_impact). How can I categorized it so that url structure would be same. For eg:

> volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/volunteering-impact-2013

for taxonomy and

volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/women-empowerment-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hyphens (`-`) to separate words in custom taxonomies and custom post types is just bad practice. You should never use any special characters, numbers or uppercase letters in taxonomy/custom post type names as they are extemely troublesome later in naming custom templates. These breaks the template hierarchy and any custom made templates will be ignored from being used. You can go and try this out for yourself. Only underscores (`_`) should be used.

I always try to use single words for taxonomy and post type names as they are less prone to fail in situations like these. The are also cleaner to use.

To keep the URL structure you are after, you should create a custom rewrite rule to handle that for you

**EDIT**

Here is the code to add a custom taxonomy and custom post type to your theme. Just add this in your functions.php. Go and play around with the code

```
function event_post_example() {

register_post_type( 'event_type',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Events Posts', 'baretheme'),
        'singular_name' => __('Event Post', 'baretheme'),
        'all_items' => __('All Event Posts', 'baretheme'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New Event Post', 'baretheme'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event Type', 'baretheme'),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'baretheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Post Types', 'baretheme'),
        'new_item' => __('New Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'view_item' => __('View Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found in the Database.', 'baretheme'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'baretheme'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ), /* end of arrays */
    'description' => __( 'This is the example event post type', 'baretheme' ), /* Custom Type Description */
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'postids_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 9,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png',
    'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'event_type', 'with_front' => false ),
    'has_archive' => 'event_type',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,

    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
    ) /* end of options */
); /* end of register post type */

register_taxonomy( 'event_cat','event_type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Category:', 'baretheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Category Name', 'baretheme' )
    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-slug' ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'event_cat', 'event_type' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'event_post_example');
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but for SEO I have to use more than single word for custom post type and taxonomy. It is very hard to compete with single keyword and google suggest to use hyphens (-) to separate word. Google consider underscore as a word joiner. Could you please help me to make custom post type and taxonomy without using any plugins. I had tried to make custom taxonomy by the instruction of this site http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/ but while making taxonomy of two words. It could not show me taxonomy.

Comment: I just arrived at work. Posting from my phone now again. Will post the code this afternoon if I get home :-)

Comment: Can I use hyphens (-) for separating words in post type name and taxonomy name by using above code. When I separate post type name by hyphens (-), it causes problem in pagination.

Comment: is baretheme is the theme name ? So what I suppose to write, if my theme name is 'vintheme'. Should I replace baretheme with vintheme?

Comment: That is what I have spoken about using hyphens. Hyphens causes a lot of issues in wordpress when used in names. They **should not ever** be used at all in taxonomy and post type names. There is no way that you can change this. Either you choose SEO and hyphens and have all these issues, or you stick to wordpress standards, use underscores and suffer a bit on SEO. You can't unfortunately have both

Comment: Is it possible to give exactly same name to post type, taxonomy and page. I want to make uniform URL structure. Suppose http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteers_impact/volunteering-impact-2013/, here volunteers_impact is taxonomy name and while going to single page of custom post type, for eg http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteer-impact/women-empowerment-2013/, here volunteer-impact is the custom post type name. You can see the difference between name of custom post type and taxonomy. I want to make both custom post type name and taxonomy name same, that is volunteer-impact.

Comment: I am using gdcpt custom post type plugin for this site. and that plugins suggest to use only underscore to join word of taxonomy and post type name. But here I use Hyphens (-) for post type name (volunteer-impact). So it causes problem in pagination. If you visit this link http://www.volunteeringnepal.com/volunteers_impact/volunteering-impact-2010/ , we will see problem of duplication of content while going to next page by pagination. Can You help to solve this problem ?

Comment: Names needs to be unique. Please read and reread what I have given you so far. You **cannot** use hypens in custom taxonomy names and custom post type names, period. There is no work around. **USE UNDERSCORES**